# HorizontalScrollView inside ViewPager, want scrolling on both

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-gesture

I have a ViewPager which displays a bunch of fragments. These fragments have a HorizontalScrollView as root view.

I would like the user to be able to swipe the HorizontalScrollView with the regular gesture until it reaches the "edge", and then, if the user continues swiping, I want to swipe to the next or previous ViewPager page.

I have been trying many different things with onTouchEvent, onInterceptTouchEvent, dispatchTouchEvent, canScroll, onOverScrolled... both by extending the ViewPager and the HorizontalScrollView but I didn't get it to work yet.

Any tips, ideas or suggestions on how to tackle this problem are highly welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Why not let the user scroll the HorizontalScrollView till you reach the "edge" of the view and then swipe to the next ViewPager view? That's what other apps are doing, what a normal user would expect and  shouldn't apps be all about the user? It's rather irritating if every app introduces new ways to navigate especially since a HorizontalScrollView in a ViewPager isn't uncommon.

Comment: Ok, that could work as well. Do you know how to achieve that? I will update the question.

Comment: Yes I do. I'll write an answer soon.

Comment: What's your minimum API level? I'm asking since it should work without any extra code from API 14 on.

Comment: Minimum API level is 14.

Comment: So it should work without any extra code. What happens in your case?

Comment: The scroll on the HorizontalScrollView works fine, but once you are in the edge of it and you keep swiping, it doesn't trigger a page change in the ViewPager. Well, actually, it does trigger it if you try enough times. So, once I'm in the edge, if I do a single swipe, nothings changes, but if I do 2-3 quick swipes, then the ViewPager changes page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55939/discussion-between-jordi-chacon-and-emanuel-moecklin).